# Write to public Google Spreadsheet without your Username & Password

Tags: python, google-sheets

I am following this [guide by google](https://developers.google.com/gdata/articles/python_client_lib), on how to access a spreadsheet with a python library. But: Then I have to write my google username and password without encryption in a python script, which is a huge security issue for me, especially, when you give the script away to others.

So: Is there a way to write to a (public) Google spreadsheet with python without providing a username & password?

[Downloading data from there is possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19397414/python-read-from-google-spreadsheet-without-username-and-password).

Comment: Move your secret data to external file, e.g. `auth.py`, than just import it in your main file. And never share `auth.py`

Comment: `ClientLogin` is only one of the authentication mechanisms, and not the usual one you want to use. You can also use `AuthSub`, `OAuth`, or (usually the best) `OAuth 2`. Read more of the documentation than just the hello world example, e.g., [Authorizing Requests](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/?csw=1#authorizing_requests) in the Google Spreadsheets documentation.

Answer (score 1):

The `OAuth 2` hint was a good one. I found [PyDrive](https://github.com/googledrive/PyDrive).

From the [docs of PyDrive](http://pythonhosted.org/PyDrive/quickstart.html#authentication):

Drive API requires OAuth2.0 for authentication. PyDrive makes your life much easier by handling complex authentication steps for you.

1. Go to [APIs Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/) and make your own project.
2. On ‘Services’ menu, turn Drive API on.
3. On ‘API Access’ menu, create OAuth2.0 client ID.
4. Select ‘Application type’ to be Web application.
5. Input `http://localhost:8080/` for both ‘Redirect URIs’ and ‘JavaScript origins’.
6. Click ‘Download JSON’ on the right side of Client ID to download **client_secrets.json**

client_secrets.json is the file that has all authentication information of your application. Put this file in your working directory.

```
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth

gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.LocalWebserverAuth() # Creates local webserver and auto handles authentication
```

Run this code and you will see a web browser asking you for authentication. Click Accept and you are done with authentication. For more details, take a look at documentation: [OAuth made easy](http://pythonhosted.org/PyDrive/oauth.html).